# "Almost everywhere" in the Pontryagin Maximum Principle?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, calculus-of-variations

In several accounts of the Pontryagin Maximum Principle, I have found that the statement says that the conclusion must hold for *almost all* $t$ (e.g., books by Clarke, Agrachev-Sachkov, etc.), and in other accounts (e.g., Wikipedia, notes by Evans) it is ascertained that it must hold for *all* $t$. So, which one is true? Does it vary according to the specific setting? Are there known counterexamples?

Thanks a lot in advance!